# Why certain row shows different column's data in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, streamwriter, read-write

I want to write `certain column` from `input file` to the `output file`.
My code looks like this:

```
try
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"outputfile.csv", true))
            {
                string[] lines;
                file.WriteLine("Date,Entity, ProdFamily, ProdGroup, ProdType1, ProdTypo, ProdType, Currency, InternalFlag, B/S");
                lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"inputfile.csv";
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line != lines[0])
                        {   
                            string[] values = line.Split(',');
                            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}",
                                    values[43], values[0], values[11], values[12], values[13], values[15], values[14], values[28], values[22], values[9]);                  
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

The `error` I get is some of the `row` are showing `other column's data`. For example, the first column of the first row shows `N` when it should shows `1-Jun-20.`

[image]

This is the part of input file that is being used for example above.

[image]

I try to hardcode by changing the column index for the defect row such as changing `values[43]` to `values[43+2]` but it just creates another unexpected data. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file has commas in some of the cells:
[image]

In the CSV, that will be represented like:

```
...,BL,"BR BSS PLC,WB,",NA,...
```

Your splitting code treats each of those commas equally, without accounting for whether they're being quoted or not:

```
string[] values = line.Split(',');
```

You should use a CSV Parsing library instead of trying to parse it yourself.

Comment: How can I tell the program to take into account `whether they're being quoted or not` ? `CSV Parsing Library` such as `CSVReader` ?

Comment: @irhamdollah Telling the program to take the quotes into account is tricky, and not easy to explain in a short comment or answer. That's why it's smart to use a parsing library where someone else has solved the hard parts, and "telling the program" to do it just involves a few lines of code. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a popular library for this purpose.